# Bitset to float or double value c++

Tags: c++, floating-point, bitset

I have two IEEE754 binary representation bitsets of float(32bit) and double (64bit).
How I can convert this bitsets to REAL float or double number?

Answer (score 5):

Use `bitset::to_ullong()` and `memcpy()` the bits.

Comment: Note though that will only work on systems using that format for floats which is *not guaranteed* (maybe endianness, maybe just different formats entirely). If you need to support other systems, an actual conversion will be needed.

Comment: @FireLancer I don't think you're correct. The intermediate `ulong` will simply store whatever the bitset had, and we already know it's in IEEE754.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz And if the system the code is running on is *not* IEEE754, then the result `float` or `double` you `memcpy` into will not have the expected value.

Comment: Right, that's true.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that does not rely on the C++ implementation using IEEE-754 types.

Let `s` be the first bit of the bitset.

Let `e` be the next 8 or 11 bits for 32-bit or 64-bit, respectively.

Let `f` be the remaining 23 or 52 bits, respectively.

Let `Ebias` be 127 or 1023, respectively.

Let `Emax` be 255 or 2047, respectively.

Let `Fscale` be 0x1p-23 or 0x1p-52, respectively.

Then this code returns the value of the bitset interpreted as an IEEE-754 basic binary floating-point object:

```
// Interpret the sign.
double S = s ? -1 : +1;

// Classify the exponent.
if (e == 0)
    // The value is zero or subnormal.
    return S * std::ldexp(f*Fscale, 1-Ebias);

else if (e < eMax)
    // The value is normal.
    return S * std::ldexp(1 + f*Fscale, e-Ebias);

else
    // The value is NaN or infinite.
    if (f == 0)
        // The value is infinite.
        return S * INFINITY;
    else
        // The value is a NaN.
        return NAN;
```

This does not set all the bits in the NAN (including the sign bit) to match the exact bits in the bitset. There is no portable way to do that; it would typically have to be done by copying the bits into `float` or `double` object using `memcpy` or other copying via a character type, and it requires that the C++ implementation be using a `float` or `double` type that is IEEE-754. And, of course, the above requires that the C++ implementation support `NAN` and `INFINITY`, and that the the floating-point type in the C++ implementation be capable of representing the value.

Answer (score 0):

First off, one does not simply represent a [IEEE 754 floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754). There is a lot that goes into such a representation. Let's say that you're given a `bitset` variable: `param` and you want to convert it to a `float`. To guarantee this is a valid conversion you'll need to ensure:

- `param.size() == sizeof(float) * CHAR_BIT`
- The [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) from which `param` was encoded matches `endian::native`
- `numeric_limits<float>::is_iec559` is true
- The radix with which `param` was encoded matches `numeric_limits<float>::radix`

If all these are true then effectively these bits are in the format of your internal floating point representation, and you can convert with a simple function like this (provided that `sizeof(unsigned long) == sizeof(float)` and `sizeof(unsigned long long) == sizeof(double)`):

```
double foo(const bitset<sizeof(double) * CHAR_BIT>& param) {
    const auto val = param.to_ullong();
    double result;

    memcpy(&result, &val, sizeof(double));

    return result;
}

float foo(const bitset<sizeof(float) * CHAR_BIT>& param) {
    const auto val = param.to_ulong();
    float result;

    memcpy(&result, &val, sizeof(float));

    return result;
}
```

Comment: `is_iec559` is not a generally useful indicator. `is_iec559` should be true if the type, including arithmetic and other behaviors, conforms to IEC 60559/IEEE 754. However, many C++ implementations use IEEE-754 formats but do not conform to its arithmetic requirements and hence do not set `is_iec559`. So `is_iec559` is not useful as an indicator of whether an IEEE-754 format is in use.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yeah... the key point though is that floating points which are *not* IEEE 754 *never* set this though. I was going to work through demonstrating how you could extract the bits to reformulate a floating point that was not IEEE 754 compliant... but then I realized probably no one will ever look at this answer so there's little reason to expand it beyond the most simplistic use case.